# IndexedDB - Como utiliza-lo?

Tags: javascript

Boa noite a todos. Estava procurando algo sobre  IndexedDB, e não obtive um retorno sólido. Os materiais que encontrei estão todos quase que sem nexo algum. Alguém poderia me explicar mesmo que resumidamente sobre o  IndexedDB?

*Na verdade o que estou pensando em fazer*

Estou estudando a possibilidade de salvar dados sem necessariamente utilizar  php, ou mysql. São dados simples, que naõ necessitam de segurança.

Comment: Há uma incerteza +/- grande se a comunidade vai adotar `IndexedDB` ou `SQLLite`, e por isso o suporte em browsers não é geral. Que tipo e quantidade de dados queres guardar? Será que o `localStorage` chega para isso?

Comment: Sérgio, acabei de ver que o localStorage é a melhor opção para mim, e juntamente com o filesaver.js.  Agradeço a sua ajuda, e até mais.

Comment: normalmente pra essas coisas de browser eu procuro documentação na MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API